# Convert blob to PDF and save to S3 using AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to convert a document file to `PDF` and upload to `S3` using my browser.

The `API` i'm using to convert the file is returning a `blob`. How can i convert the `blob` to a `PDF` file and save it to `S3`?

Currently my code looks like this

```
function addFile(file) {
    console.log("File!", file);

    var fileName = Date.now().toString();
    var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent("files") + '/';

    var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
    s3.upload({
        Key: photoKey,
        Body: file + ".pdf",
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
        }
        alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    });
}
```

I tried converting the blob to a file using this

```
var file = new File([blobData], "filename.pdf", {type: "application/pdf", lastModified: Date.now()});
```

and then passed the file to the `addFile()` function but it creates a file which contains `[object File].pdf` as it's content.

How can i create a PDF file with the blob contents?

Comment: Blobs and Files tend to be interchangeable for most native js apis. No conversion is needed. And the blob is probably already in a pdf format again no conversion needed. Also [`Body`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)  is supposed to be any of Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream. It is not supposed to be the filename

Comment: Are you starting out with a PDF file already?  If not, then you'll have to use a library to generate a PDF.  It's not as simple as just converting a BLOB.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen @PatrickEvans I am using `Cloudmersive API` https://github.com/Cloudmersive/Cloudmersive.APIClient.NodeJS.DocumentAndDataConvert/blob/master/client/docs/ConvertDocumentApi.md#example-1 and it's giving me a blob and when i `console.log` it's response its showing some PDF encoding stuff but when i pass that to S3 i get an empty file on it

Comment: @PatrickEvans when i give the buffer i am getting an empty pdf file being stored on S3

Comment: You mean when you have just  `Body: blobVariable,`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yep, when i give the blobvariable

Comment: @PatrickEvans, The response is a base64 encoded octet-stream which decodes to a PDF encoded file

Answer (score 2):

To convert base64 string to PDF on fly and write on s3 as a file, I used this approach -

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const S3 = new AWS.S3();
    const base64String = 'abcxyz';
    let buffer = new Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
    let params = {
        Bucket : 'your-bucket-name',
        Key : 'user.pdf', 
        Body : buffer
    }
    S3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else
            console.log(data.Location)
    })
```

Well, the other approach is to first create pdf from this string on your local machine using 'fs' module. 
And to submit it to S3, read that pdf first and then upload to s3. But this is a lazy process and I personally dont recommend it.

Hope it helps.